# jQuery FadeOut not working after modifying css z-index toggle

Tags: jquery, css, z-index, fadein, fadeout

I'm having trouble with fading out an image on toggle using jQuery. What I'm doing is first hiding the image, then fading it in and increasing the z-index so that it appears above another image im using. This works fine, but the issue is making it fade out after hovering (the css modification works fine - the image goes back to being behind the first image but does not fade out while doing so).
Here's my script:

```
//world map hover
    $(".worldimg").hide();
    $("#worldnumber1").hover(function () {
        $("#world1").fadeIn("slow");
        $("#world1").css('z-index', 200);
    }, function () {
        $("#world1").fadeOut("slow");
        $("#world1").css('z-index', 20);
    });
```

Would appreciate some help ^^

Comment: Can we have a jsFiddle ? :)

Comment: when you post working JSFiddle with your issue, we can reproduce it and is easier resolve it and help you

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the callback of the `fade*()` functions, because you need to change `z-index` when fadeIn/fadeOut is finished:

```
//world map hover
$(".worldimg").hide();
$("#worldnumber1").hover(function () {
    $("#world1").fadeIn("slow", function() {
       $(this).css('z-index', 200);
    });
}, function () {
    $("#world1").fadeOut("slow", function() {
        $(this).css('z-index', 20);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try events as `mouseenter` and `mouseleave`, something like:

```
$(".worldimg").hide();
$("#worldnumber1").mouseenter(function () {
    $("#world1").fadeIn("slow");
    $("#world1").css('z-index', 200);
});
$("#worldnumber1").mouseleave(function () {
    $("#world1").fadeOut("slow");
    $("#world1").css('z-index', 20);
});
```